# Getting image src into a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp with a file chooser. I need to take the 'src' of the image to a servlet.How to do this.

```html
<img id="imgEventImage" src="img/Addmovie/ET000242281bb9.jpg" alt="your image">
<div class="ratingBox">
<div class="Add_TrailerMusic">
<div id="upFileImg" class="upld btn-imageUpload" style="margin-left: 28px;">
<span>Add Poster</span>
<input  id="selectfileImg" name="posterPath" class="uploadImg" style="color: transparent;"type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: More input. Show jsp and explain more.

Comment: @Jan I want to get the image src to a servlet.

Comment: You will not get image src - you'll receive image data. search for "upload images from jsp" and you'll find help i think.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to pass parameter to the Servlet from the JSP by using JavaScript...

If so, then it may help.

Make a hidden field inside the form, for example:

```
<form name="formName" method="POST">
  <!-- other fields -->
  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenFieldName" id="hiddenFieldId" value=""/>  
  <input type="button" name="submitTheFormBtn" onclick="submitTheForm()"/>
</form>
```

Then submit the form to the server via JavaScript:

```
<script>

function submitTheForm() {
   var imgSrcParam = document.getElementById("imgEventImage").src;
   document.getElementById("someFieldId").value = imgSrcParam;
   document.forms[formName].submit();
   /*or give an id to the form you want to submit, 
    then use document.getElementById("formId").submit()*/
}

</script>
```

In the Servlet you can get this parameter:

```
String imgSrcParam = request.getParameter("hiddenFieldName");
```